# DirectX 11.0 World Transform

Tags: c++, directx

I am trying to render a cube in world space when i pass world XMMatrix as an Identity matrix , the cube gets rendered fine :
[image: Proper Cube]

But when i try to add translation and scaling factors to the world matrix
i get this :
[image: Problem]

```
/************************ TRANSFORM.CPP *********************/
m_position = { 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f };
m_scale = { 1.0f,1.0f,1.0f };   

DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_matrix_translation , 
DirectX::XMMatrixTranslation(m_position.x, m_position.y, m_position.z));
DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_matrix_scalar,DirectX::XMMatrixScaling(m_scale.x, m_scale.y, m_scale.z));

 /************************* RENDER.CPP ***********************************/

DirectX::XMMATRIX view = gp_MainCameraH->GetXM_View();
DirectX::XMMATRIX world = GetXM_Scalar() * GetXM_Translation(); // if this is kept as Identity matrix , the cube gets rendered fine ( first image)
DirectX::XMMATRIX proj = gp_MainCameraH->GetXM_Projection();

DirectX::XMMATRIX vp = view * proj;
DirectX::XMMATRIX wvp = world * vp;
// Set the constant buffer of the shader
RenderStateManager::GetEffectVariable("gWorldViewProj")->SetMatrix(reinterpret_cast<float*>(&(wvp)));
```

Comment: Last part probably should be `wvp = ::DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose((world * view) * proj);`

Comment: Nope i get a blank screen , nothing visible.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the transform class ,it was creating blank world matrix.